# Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'PlayerMovement.OnFire(InputValue)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float runSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] float climbSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] Vector2 deathKick = new Vector2(10f, 10f);
    [SerializeField] GameObject bullet;
    [SerializeField] Transform gun;

    Vector2 moveInput;
    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    Animator myAnimator;
    CapsuleCollider2D myBodyCollider;
    BoxCollider2D myFeetCollider;
    float gravityScaleAtStart;

    bool isAlive = true;

    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        myBodyCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider2D>();
        myFeetCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        gravityScaleAtStart = myRigidbody.gravityScale;

    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        if(!isAlive )
        {return;}
        Die();
        Run();
        FlipSprite();
        ClimbLadder();
        OnFire();
    }

    void OnFire(InputValue value)
    {
        if (!isAlive)
        { return; }

       
            Instantiate(bullet, gun.position, transform.rotation);
        
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue value)
    {
        moveInput = value.Get<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log(moveInput);

    }

    void OnJump(InputValue value)
    {
        if (!myBodyCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground")))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (value.isPressed)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity += new Vector2(0f, jumpSpeed);
        }
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Vector2 playerVelocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * runSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
        myRigidbody.velocity = playerVelocity;


        bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon;

        myAnimator.SetBool("isRunning", playerHasHorizontalSpeed);
        
         
        
    }

    void FlipSprite()
    {
         bool playerHasHorizontalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.x) > Mathf.Epsilon;

        if (playerHasHorizontalSpeed)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector2(Mathf.Sign(myRigidbody.velocity.x), 1f);
        }
    }

    void ClimbLadder()
    {

        if (!myBodyCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Climbing")))
        {
            myRigidbody.gravityScale = gravityScaleAtStart;
            myAnimator.SetBool("isClimbing", false);
            return;
        }

        Vector2 climbVelocity = new Vector2( myRigidbody.velocity.x, moveInput.y * climbSpeed);


        myRigidbody.velocity = climbVelocity;

        myRigidbody.gravityScale = 0f;

        bool playerHasVerticalSpeed = Mathf.Abs(myRigidbody.velocity.y) > Mathf.Epsilon;
        myAnimator.SetBool("isClimbing", playerHasVerticalSpeed);
    }


    void Die()
    {
        if(myBodyCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Enemies" , "Hazards")))
        {
            isAlive = false;
            myAnimator.SetTrigger("Dying");
            myRigidbody.velocity = deathKick;
        }
    }

  
}
```

I am learning game development from Udemy course- Tile Vania - Lecture 100. The above code works perfectly fine before adding OnFire() method. After adding OnFire() method, I come across the above error. value parameter of reference type InputValue is not recognized in OnFire() method. I have no clue what needs to done here. Please help!

Comment: Trying to be friendly here - StackOverflow is not a basic programming course. You define void OnFire(InputValue value), which means it takes a parameter (of type InputValue). When you call that method, you have to call it with that parameter as argument (that's what your error message says). I guess that you don't want that parameter, so remove the stuff between the braces in line 50 or so (so that void OnFire(InputValue value) instead reads void OnFire())

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code isin `c#`

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `OnFire` method in `Update()`, you need to pass the `InputValue value` parameter to the method.

That is, it should be like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if(!isAlive )
    {return;}
    Die();
    Run();
    FlipSprite();
    ClimbLadder();
    OnFire(value);
}
```

Of course before defining the value value

Answer (score 0):

**Remove OnFire() method in Update().**
The methods created in `Input System` package don't need called in the Update method.
For example, you don't call `OnMove()` or `OnJump()` in `Update()` but their works.